# Spatie/Laravel cors issue in production

Tags: laravel, cors

This cors issue will be the death of me. Anyways I am trying to trouble shoot why the [spatie/cors](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors) package works locally but does not in production. If anybody has experience with this I would appreciate the help!! I am trying to access my backend but getting an alarm saying

```
my url has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request
```

Comment: Do you have something like a HTTP --> HTTPS redirect in place, perhaps?

Comment: to be honest I am not sure. The certificate was generated using `LetsEncrypt` and it didn't give me any details of the certificate.

Comment: The issue wouldn't be with the certificate, or Let's Encrypt. It'd be your webserver config or application trying to redirect requests from HTTP to HTTPS. Take a look at the network panel in your browser's developer tools - I suspect you'll see the `OPTIONS` request in there getting a 301/302 response.

Comment: I am not getting anything in my network tab of my console. when I refresh it just shows the resources loaded.

Comment: If the console is showing a failed request, there should be *something* in the network tab that corresponds. Perhaps you can share the URL?

Comment: @ceejayoz, aewcpa.traxit.io

Comment: @TJWeems try to insert into your main app HTML header with this `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: @Magnetic do you mean on my front end app that is making the requests? Should I include it in my axios header as well?

Comment: @TJWeems, yes try it if you use Laravel backend. You could success in local, but you shouldn't in production, because that is different browser. Please learn with this link firstly, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS and check your correct reference back-end link in front-end, also check this link https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors if you didn't added it. Good luck~:)

Answer (score 1):

Your URL `https://aewcpa.traxit.pro/api/account` is returning a 301 redirect to `https://traxit.pro/api/account` for the CORS `OPTIONS` request, which is causing this issue.

You can see this in action in your browser's network console, or with cURL:

[image]

```
curl -I 'https://aewcpa.traxit.pro/api/account' -X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -H 'Referer: https://aewcpa.traxit.io/login' -H 'Origin: https://aewcpa.traxit.io'

HTTP/2 301 
server: nginx/1.15.6
date: Fri, 21 Dec 2018 18:14:36 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 169
location: https://traxit.pro/api/account
```

Comment: so is the a configuration issue on my nginx server or the code of my project? Im sorry I am just don't have much experience with network issues

Comment: The redirect's HTML returned by `https://aewcpa.traxit.pro/api/account` does look like it's nginx doing the redirect to me. Laravel's redirects look different.

Comment: okay, well I am using forge to host the site which is actually using digital ocean. are there options in digital ocean for nginx server to handle such requests?

Comment: I'm not enormously familiar with Forge, but my understanding is it configures things like nginx for you. I'd suspect something's going on where it's configured to canonicalize your URLs based on the value of `APP_URL`.

Comment: Yeah I don't know. I just don't understand why it would work in my local enviroment and not in production. I have tried explicitly placing the url in my access origin with no change.

Comment: I added `*.myurl.com` to the nginx config file located in laravel forge which solved the 301 moved permantly issue. Now I am trying to figure out 405 alarm lol